# Where have they hidden the DotNetOpenAuth API documentation?

Tags: api, documentation, dotnetopenauth

I am pretty sure I looked in the most common places but I can't seem to find the documentation for the DotNetOpenAuth API. Almost every link forwards to docs.dotnetopenauth.net which doesn't seem to excist.

Does anyone know where they've hidden the docs?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Digging through the Google-Cache is **NOT** the way to go here :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version you're using:

- http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v4.0/
- http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/
- http://docs.dotnetopenauth.net/master/

The site was down for a day or so.  But it's back up now.

Comment: That URL is dead again. Will it be back or is the API stored somewhere else now?

Comment: +1. Can't access the site anymore! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of the docs. Don't know if its up-to-date but is contains information with better markup than the Google cache;)
[click](http://dopehacker.appspot.com/www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/)

**EDIT: Site is already online now**

Comment: not the docs I was looking for, but thanks anyway :)