# How to get started with OAuth to secure a Web API application?

Tags: c#, security, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API application and I've understood OAuth would be the standard security model for APIs where an Authentication Server would become responsible to generate Authorization Tokens so that the user can send to our server and consume the services.

I'm very new to this but I understand the roles involved:

- Resource Owner
- Client
- Resource Server
- Authorization Server

But what is OAuth exactly in practice, not in theory? Is it a .NET library? Is it a service provided by a separate Company? Is it something I can configure on my local development machine and see how it works?

How to get started with OAuth to secure a Web API application?

Answer (score 17):

OAuth is a protocol; the current version is [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/).  More to your question, that link lists several implementations of the protocol in various technologies.  For use with the .NET Web API you're probably interested in [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) which provides implementations of both OAuth 1 and OAuth 2.

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth in an app I'm working on now to secure a .NET Web API.  I've got an `OAuth2Handler` which extends [`DelegatingHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx) which is inserted into the Web API pipeline before incoming requests reach any controllers.  `OAuth2Handler` does the following:

1. Instantiates a DotNetOpenAuth `ResourceServer`
2. Calls `ResourceServer.GetPrincipal()` which reads and decrypts an access
   token (issued elsewhere by the `AuthorizationServer` and returns an
   `OAuthPrincipal`  (In my case I'm reading additional data that the DotNetOpenAuth implementation allows you to pass and creating a [`ClaimsPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.aspx).)
3. Assigning the `IPrincipal` containing the user information read from the access token to the User property of the thread and current HTTP context so it is available from the [`ApiController.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.user%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property in the service controllers:  `httpContext.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;`

Honestly, getting this all working (e.g. setting up the authorization server, resource server, certificates, etc.) isn't trivial.  Unfortunately there didn't seem to be a good guide on the DotNetOpenAuth site.  Here's a few other tasks you'll have ahead of you if you go this route:

- **Implement `IAuthorizationServer`** - This is the interface provided by
  DotNetOpenAuth that allows you to plug in to the library and use
  their implementation to issue OAuth2 access tokens.   You'll also need to implement `INonceStore` and `ICryptoKeyStore` which I did using an EntityFramework context for storage.
- **Configure Certificates** - The `AuthorizationServer` and `ResourceServer` each use certificates to encrypt/decrypt the access token ensuring they are only accessible to each other.  I built some [custom configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) so I could manage this configuration in the `web.config` files of my authorization server app and my Web API services (resource server).
- **Manage Refresh Token** - When first requesting an access token from the authorization server you'll get back (depending on your configuration) both an OAuth2 refresh token and an access token.  The services use the access token which should be short-lived.  The refresh token is used to get more access tokens.  The refresh token should be kept secret (whatever that means in your scenario).  For me it means the refresh token is never exposed to client-side javascript in my web app.

I hope that helps give you a high level idea of how to get started with OAuth and .NET Web API.  Here's [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukadc/archive/2012/05/24/claim-based-security-for-asp-net-web-apis-using-dotnetopenauth.aspx) demonstrating some of these steps. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286324/authenticate-client-side-app-to-rest-api-using-cors-with-local-strategy/16313669#16313669) gives a few more high level details of the client side of the picture.

(The DotNetOpenAuth online docs appear to be down right now... sorry for no links to them;  Apparently it has [happened before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733823/where-have-they-hidden-the-dotnetopenauth-api-documentation)).

Comment: Any chance you could share some source code. I've been playing with this for a couple of hours and it's a bit of a PITA. The DotNetOpenAuth docs didn't help much in this particular instance.