# Authentication method in Cloud

Tags: rest, authentication, azure, cloud

I am developing a authentication service that authenticate the client service based on the credential and after authentication, client service would be eligble to access restful api to put and get data.
Please guide me which cloud service i can use for above scenario and i have following limitation while chosing authentication method.

1. As per the above scenario, Client service would access the restful
   api so i can not maintain client session in restful api so i can not
   use any token authentication method.
2. I need to achive cloud agnostic so same authentication service
   should available in Google, Amazon and Azure.

Comment: use Windows Azure Active Directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement OAuth 2.0 which is a standard:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028912/1384539

and here

http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/10/11/oauth-2-0-in-web-api/

if you need something easier, take a look at basic authentication:

http://christianspecht.de/2013/08/02/basic-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: thanks for reply. Can i implement SAML authentication in RESTful API ?

Comment: @Kuldeep it's possible but SAML tokens tend to be too heavy weight for WebAPIs. It's better use JWT (JSON web tokens), they're SAML in JSON format instead of XML.